# Umbraco 7 - Members with limited editing permission

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco

I'm exploring Umbraco to be used as a CMS for a communication and information sharing website.
The website is geographically organized, and each country will have its set of pages.
In this website, some registered users (Members) can have the possibility to edit some part of the website, based on the country the member is assigned to.

Members will sign in by them-self to the portal, by sign-up, or using a facebook account (Oauth authentication), then the site admin will give them editing permissions. So they will be able to edit the content for their country.

Is there an easy way to make this customization with Umbraco 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By members, you probably mean users? Users are for the Umbraco backend, members are for ekstranets and stuff ("website users").

The easiest way to do this is the assign each user a start node in Umbraco - if a user has a country node set as their starting node, all siblings and ancestors of that node will be inaccessible, but they can see whatever child nodes the country has.

Comment: Actually there isn't a clear distinction between members and users. In particular we can say that in this project the client wants to have members with high privileged, as they should act as a normal registered members and more they can edit, with several limits, some pages and sections of the website. Your solution could work, it was what I was thinking, but as the community starts to grow, it becomes hard to manage (~150 countries, with 3~4 editors each one..). I'm wondering if it could be better to build a customized CMS from scratch

Comment: In Umbraco there is that distinction. Members don't have Umbraco backend access. Umbraco 8 miiiight just have user groups which would make your scenario easier to maintain, but you should have put your thoughts and those numbers in your question. And no, building your own CMS from scratch is probably not better. Umbraco is open source, so if you need something specific you can extend Umbraco the way you want. User groups would be easier to implement than building it all from scratch, right?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want something more like a wiki rather than a CMS like Umbraco... maybe look into a different piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Umbraco ContentService (used by Umbraco it's self) to allow for users to edit content by creating forms on the frontend and have the Users set up at Members. Then create a group/permissions type by country.

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/Management/Services/ContentService

Else like suggested you could create them as Users and set permissions so they can only access the pages on their country.

More detail on you requirements might give better answers. I would want to know are the Users members of the company or public users? Do you require rollback facility? etc